# Database not consistent when accessed from different source files

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a program in Python composed of 4 source files. One of them is the main file which imports the other 3. As I work with a small Sqlite database, I am creating tables in one of the "secondary" source files, but when I access the database again from the main source file, the tables just populated before are empty.

Can I save the tables' content in a more consistent way? I am quite surprised with what is happening.

So in the main file I typed:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("bayes.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select count(*) from TableA")
print cur.fetchone()
```

The result is 0 (rows). 
Just before, in another source file I do the same thing and get size=8 of TableA.

Comment: Just throwing this out there, did you make sure that those programs successfully committed the information to the db? (call `.commit()`)

Comment: No,  I didnt do that! I knew there must be something missing ! I didn't see in any tutorial though.. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call the `commit` function in order to save your changes in the database. You can see the full documentation here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit